# android coding java excute su command android not work

Tags: java, android, terminal, su

i have a device rooted by magisk. i want to make an app to excute "su ls data/data". But when i run app it only returned two packages eg: com.google.android.gms, com.nghiatd.nghiaclicker( this is package name of my app). But when i excute that command on terminal emulator app it returned full package name of apps in data/data folder. i have added read,write,ACCESS_SUPERUSER permission in manifest. magisk granted permission.i have tested on android 10. that funtion returned full package name of all apps. anyone know why android 12 does not return full ? This is funtion:

`

```
    enter code here

public static String executeCommandSU( String command)
    {
            try {
                Process process = new ProcessBuilder().command("su").start();
                process.getOutputStream().write((command + "\n").getBytes("ASCII"));
                //process.getOutputStream().write(("ls data" + "\n").getBytes("ASCII"));
                process.getOutputStream().flush();
                SystemClock.sleep(3000);
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                BufferedReader bre = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
                while (bre.ready()) {
                    sb.append(bre.readLine());
                }
                String s = sb.toString();
                if (!s.replaceAll(" ", "").equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                    Log.e("SystemHelper", "Error with command: " + s);
                    return s;
                }
                sb = new StringBuffer();
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
                while (br.ready()) {
                    sb.append(br.readLine()+"\n");
                }
                s = sb.toString();
                if (!s.replaceAll(" ", "").equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                    Log.e("`SystemHelper`", "Output from command: " + s);
                    return s;
                }
                return s;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                 Log.e("SystemHelper", "Error executing: " + command, e);
            }
        return "";
    }`
```

`

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    requestPermission();
    //String s=executeCommand(new String[]{"su","-c","ls data/data"});
    String s=executeCommandSU("ls data/data");
    Log.i("vvvvv",s);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"aaaaaaa: ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Could you please correct the code? You posted `executeCommandSU` twice.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `ready()` incorrectly. Look up the docs to see why. Change:

```
 while (br.ready()) {
     sb.append(br.readLine()+"\n");
 }
```

to

```
 while (true) {
     String l = br.readLine();
     if (l == null) // EOF
         break;
     sb.append(l+"\n");
 }
```

Do the same for the error stream.

Also to make `su` terminate change:

```
process.getOutputStream().write((command + "\n").getBytes("ASCII"));
```

to:

```
process.getOutputStream().write((command + "\nexit\n").getBytes("ASCII"));
```

Haven't tested it. Hope it works.

Comment: it returned same result

Answer (score 0):

edit targetSdk 29 in build.gradle file will solve problem

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).